# PHP: pregmatch input field

Tags: php, forms

I have a html form with text input field. I'm wondering how to recognize specific input from the form. Example input commands:

```
<input type="text" name="action" value="bookmark http://google.com" />
<?php
        if ($command == "goto"):
        // go to website X
        elseif ($command == "bookmark"):
        // bookmark website X
        else:
        // something else
        endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to split the string on the first space to separate it into a command and the parameter for that command. The "2" parameter to explode() allows spaces to be used in $param, if necessary.

```
$input = explode(' ', $_POST['action'], 2);
$command = $input[0];
$param = $input[1];

switch ($command) {
    case 'goto':
        // go to website $param
        break;
    case 'bookmark':
        // bookmark website $param
        break;
    default:
        // unknown command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$request = $_POST['action'];

$split = explode(' ',$request,2);
$command = $split[0];

if(!isset($split[1])){
    //no url
    die;
}

$url = $split[1];

if($command == "goto"){

    header('location: '.$url);
    die;

}elseif($command == "bookmark"){

    header('location: '.$url);
    die;

}else{

    echo 'No Commands :(';

}
```

Use `$_POST` or `$_GET` to retrive the request data. ie: `$_GET['action']`

Set the header location to redirect the browser. `die;` or `exit;` is used to terminate and output the current script

Comment: $_POST['action'] will never be 'goto' but 'goto {url}' for example

Answer (score 0):

```
$aAct = explode(' ', $_POST['action');
if(is_array($aAct)) {
    switch($aAct[0]) {
        case 'bookmark':
            /* do action e.g. header('Location: ' . $aAct[1]); */
        break;
    }
}
```

Make a case/break combination for every action you intend to specify..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
//get the command from your value
$command = current(explode(" ", $_POST['action']));

//get the url from your value
$url     = next(explode(" ", $_POST['action']));
```

And as stated by karim79, a switch to handle the input would more appropriate.

```
switch($command) {

    case 'goto': 
         // do stuff with $url;
         break;
    case 'bookmark': 
         // do stuff with $url;
         break;
    default: // do something default;
}
```

hope it helps